# How to append / add a textbox after an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

There are 4 anchors available,
div 1,2,3,4 /div

my query is that how to add / append a textBox between 2 and 3.

please.

Comment: Did you try yourself to accomplish this?

Comment: And adding textbox between `<a></a>` tags doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
```

//Jquery after method

```
$("#2").after('<input type="text" name="somename" />');
```

Comment: Thank Deepu, but as mentioned all of them are in single div and textbox should be added next to  2 anchor. So, if use id of anchor will it be ok for me..?

Comment: @Vijay Why dont you give a try ??!